# Load font awesome by content in css

Tags: plugins, fonts

I have some trouble with Divi plugin. I need to change icon using content in css.
I add font awesome by cdn(it works on website e.g. `<i class="fa fa-eercast" aria-hidden="true"></i>` displays properly) but now I want to change existing icon from rss to instagram by changing a:before content to instagram code: `et-social-rss .icon:before{content:'\f16d'}` and it doesn't display icon. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to content, you also need to specify font family. Otherwise the browser will use whatever font Divi has assigned to that icon, which is probably not Font Awesome.

```
.get-social-rss .icon:before {
    content: '\f16d';
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you don't need to change css code, you can simply change the class to "fa fa-instagram" e.g:`<i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>`

Comment: Since the original content is set as CSS :before content, the OP is asking for a CSS way to change - without touching the HTML.